# Lock Textboxes after drag and drop

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, locking

I have 20 textboxes in my userform, they are all locked, one is filled with text and the other ones are empty. I want to drag the text from one box to the other. I unlock the textbox with text and drag the text to another textbox an drop it there. After that I want to lock both textboxes again.
The first problem is that the text is not dropped but copied and the second is that I really don't know how to lock the textboxes again after dropping the text.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_BeforeDragOver(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean, ByVal Data As MSForms.DataObject, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single, ByVal DragState As MSForms.fmDragState, ByVal Effect As MSForms.ReturnEffect, ByVal Shift As Integer)
TextBox1.Locked = False
Effect = 2
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox2_BeforeDropOrPaste(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean, ByVal Action As MSForms.fmAction, ByVal Data As MSForms.DataObject, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single, ByVal Effect As MSForms.ReturnEffect, ByVal Shift As Integer)
TextBox2.Locked = False
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox1_AfterUpdate()
TextBox1.Locked = True
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox2_AfterUpdate()
TextBox2.Locked = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not dropped but copied", what should be happening?

Comment: The text is now in both Textboxes, it is copied and paste instead of cut and paste.

Comment: Why are you doing it via dragging?

Comment: I think it is the best way for me to do it like this. In fact I have 650 textboxes in my userform and I drag the content from one box to another. But I am always open for better solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The first problem is that the text is not dropped but copied

> the second is that I really don't know how to lock the textboxes again after dropping the text.

Is this what you are trying? I have taken an example of 2 textboxes. Feel free to apply it accordingly to your project. Both the textboxes in the example below are locked. You do not need to unlock `TextBox1`.

```
Option Explicit

Dim ctl As Control

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    TextBox1.Text = "Sid"
    TextBox1.DragBehavior = fmDragBehaviorEnabled
    TextBox2.DragBehavior = fmDragBehaviorEnabled
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_BeforeDragOver(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean, _
                                    ByVal Data As MSForms.DataObject, ByVal X As Single, _
                                    ByVal Y As Single, ByVal DragState As MSForms.fmDragState, _
                                    ByVal Effect As MSForms.ReturnEffect, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Set ctl = TextBox1
    TextBox2.Locked = False
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_AfterUpdate()
    If Not ctl Is Nothing Then ctl.Text = ""
    TextBox2.Locked = True
End Sub
```

**In Action**

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much Siddarth Rout. I am going to try to fit it in my program. In fact I have 650 textboxes in my program and I must try to fit your solution in a class module. My question for 2 textboxes was for me easier to explain in a question.

Comment: This will get you started [VBA – Control Arrays](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/15/vba-control-arrays/)

Comment: Thanks again Siddarth Rout

Comment: I see where I am going wrong. In the class-module I miss the TextBox2_AfterUpdate option. I cannot choose this option there.

Comment: You have to create a common sub in class module like I showed in the link above.

Comment: This is the solution, now it works as I want it to work. Thanks for help Siddarth Rout.

Comment: Glad to be of help :)